# What to do when my system freezes?

Tags: 12.04, wubi, freeze

Ubuntu has suddenly stopped working and everything has become unresponsive, including the mouse, keyboard. I waited for almost an hour to make it settle itself. Finally, I had to shut it down and restart it and then it was ok.

details:

When this happened, I opened almost 9 tabs (i don't know whether this can cause          a crash in ubuntu). I have Ubuntu installed in windows 8 using Wubi. I never had this problem before. I use 12.04 LTS.

What might be the possible reason for this? Is this due to some mis-management of system? Or something else?

System Specifications:

> brand : Samsung
>   model : samsung np 300 e5c a02in
>   architecture : 64 bit
>   graphic card : intel 4000 hd graphic card

I don't remember installing any custom drivers manually
memory given to ubuntu partition : 30 GB (I am using far below this)
processor : 3rd gen i5.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your brand/model/graphics card/wireless (general specs). Also indicate whether you have custom drivers installed. Normally this problem would be a hardware incompatibility, but hard to know without that info. PS. Don't hard shutdown, use: [Alt+SysRq R E I S U B](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses)

Comment: Does this help?: http://askubuntu.com/questions/197418/how-do-i-configure-an-intel-hd-graphics-4000